# Convert to byte array so I can decode with ATOB

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I'm currently sending a byte array of a pdf from the server which is generated using `Converter.Convert` from the `ceTe.DynamicPDF.HtmlConverter` package.
When I try to decode it using ATOB in angular it gives this error:

> InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The
> string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

I've seen this error online and the solutions were just using other functions that have ATOB in them so the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

[`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) decodes a base64 encoded string, [`ceTe.DynamicPDF.HtmlConverter`](https://www.dynamicpdf.com/docs/dotnet/cete.dynamicpdf.conversion.htmlconverter) doesn't look like it outputs a base64 string, but a pdf, so that's going to be your issue.

Comment: I noticed. Trying to use another method from the package but for some reason the one used in the documentation seems to be obsolete. I can't find any other methods that work